# Fixing syntax highlighting in Latex documents using cleveref

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I use Vim and Latex together. I have recently been fiddling with the `cleveref` package and it kind of messed up syntax highlighting. For example, before using this package, when I wanted to crossreference something, I used this command:

```
\ref{label_name}
```

Now I use

```
\cref{label_name}
```

In the first case, vim didn't mark the underscore as illegal, even though not in math mode. However, with `cref`, the underscore is highlighted bright red. Is there a way to fix this behaviour?